# SQL Server : trigger INSERTED

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Could you please help me and explain why in this trigger doesn't want to read `Inserted.StartSession`? All the names are right, but he just doesn't see this inserted field...

Thanks

```
ALTER TRIGGER massage.Eighthourswork
ON massage.tSchedule FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   declare @DayPart datetime
   set @DayPart = INSERTED.StartSession
   --SET NOCOUNT ON

   IF (SELECT sum (cast(datepart(hour, SessionHours) as int)) 
       FROM massage.tSchedule
       WHERE Datepart(day,massage.tSchedule.StartSession) = Datepart(day, @DayPart)) = 8
      RETURN print 'Cant work more than  8 hours'
   End
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements inserts 12 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 12 rows. Which of those will your code select here?? `SET @DayPart = INSERTED.StartSession` - it's non-deterministic, one will be picked arbitrarily, and all 11 others will be ignored.....

Comment: In addition to not handling multiple row operations what is this trying to do? There seems to be some pretty problematic logic in the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

INSERTED is a (virtual) table.   You can't do this:

```
set @DayPart = INSERTED.StartSession
```

You can do this:

```
set @DayPart = SELECT TOP 1 StartSession FROM INSERTED
```

But an even better approach would be to not use a variable at all, and join to the inserted table in your IF (SELECT...) statement.   Otherwise what will happen if more than one row gets inserted at once?